# POST request in REST WCF

Tags: wcf, rest

I have developed a REST WCF service method as following:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Details")]
    DetailData GetDetails(TestData requst);


 [DataContract]
public class TestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DetailData { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to invoke the service using following client code:

```
  ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
  string testXml = "<TestData>" +
                      "<DetailData>" +
                          "4000" +
                       "</DetailData>" +
                    "</TestData>";

 string postData = testXml.ToString();
 byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
 string url = "http://localhost/WCFRestService.svc/bh/Details";
 string strResult = string.Empty;

 // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
 HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 // set method as post
 webrequest.Method = "POST";
 // set content type
 webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
 // set content length
 webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
 // get stream data out of webrequest object
 Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
 newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
 newStream.Close();

 //Gets the response
 WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
 //Writes the Response
 Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
 string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting the following error :

**"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"**

I could successfully call another service method where "GET" verb is being used. But the above client code for invoking the service using "POST" verb is not working. I think, I am missing something in Client code.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
```

to

`WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`